# How should I program logging into a website and completing actions

Tags: python, forms

Scenario: I want to log into a web page and request an export of data that will be sent to me via email. I'm most familiar with python so I start with this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

response = br.open("http://weightgurus.com/")

print response.read()      # the text of the page

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form
```

Here is the repsonse HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.module = {}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dependencies.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/components.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-29982844-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I look at the HTML from a browser I get this section:

```
<div id="loginPrompt"><form id="form" class="centerText"><div class="formGroup">Email:<input id="email" type="email" class="field"></div><div class="formGroup">Password:<input id="password" type="password" class="field"></div><div id="forgotPassword"><a href="javascript:">Forgot password?</a></div><input id="goCatcher" type="submit" style="position:absolute;margin-left:-10000px;"></form><div class="submitContainer"><div id="submit" class="h-medium popup-title text-center">Log in</div></div></div>
```

The problem is there are not forms listed for this website. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your implementation will be very specific to the page that you're accessing; the best thing here is to provide an extract of the HTML that you're trying to analyse, and the code to do it, and question where you think it's going wrong.

Comment: I added in the response HTML. The website is listed in the code. It seems as if I'm not receiving any forms when doing this programmatically, but when I use my web browser and view the HTML I can see the login and password fields.

Comment: If the content you see when running `br.open(url)` is different from your browser making a request, the site is sending you different data, likely because some part of your request is different to how your browser sends it.